# Quantum Fluctuation Contribution in the Path Integral of a Meta-stable Potential

Tags: path-integral, instantons

In Wen XiaoGang's *QFT of Many-Body Systems* Sect 2.4.2, He studied the decay of a Meta-stable state via path integral method.

The real-time potential is

[image: Real-time Potential]

A state at $x=-a$ decays to $x=\infty$.

The imaginary-time potential is

[image: Imaginary-time Potential]

He claimed that in the integral of the quantum fluctuation of the bounce process, the determination of the operator
$-\frac{d^2}{d\tau^2}+V''(x_{cl})$
has a negative eigenvalue $-\lambda$. So the quantum fluctuation contribution
$K\sim det(-\frac{d^2}{d\tau^2}+V''(x_{cl}))<0$

However, if this is the case, then let $c$ be the amplitude of this negative mode. When integrating the quantum fluctuation, we would calculate
$\int dc e^{\frac 12 \lambda c^2}$, which diverges. Does that make any sense?

P.S. After a few days' thought, I tend to believe that the reason is that the stationary phase approximation holds only in the vicinity of the classical path. So the integration of a quantum fluctuation mode should have an upper cut-off.

As to this system, the cliff of the real-time potential should have a bottom representing the true vacuum. So the high mountain of the imaginary-time potential should have a top. If we integrate the negative quantum fluctuation mode to infinity, we would climb over the mountain top and the approximation fails.

Is this idea correct? Is $K$ imaginary because of the magic of analytic continuation?

PS2. I've found the answer in *The Uses of Instantons* Sect 2.4 by Sidney Coleman. It turns that the considerations in my PS1 make sense.